# Tracking Social shares for the members -Addthis PHP Script

Tags: php, addthis

Thanks for your time to read this post. i have a tricky hosting...

i always use addthis to add facebook,twitter share . but now my requirement is in the member site, i wanted to know is that particular member shared the page to facebook/twitter? how to track that?

i am trying to build a custom app like getting member and page details and redirect to corresponding site after storing in the db, but how do we know is that redirected page completed shared? or it got closed abruptly?

```
custom_redirect.php?user_id=1&target=facebook&page=pagename
```

your suggestions are really helpful , thanks again to you all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this completely in PHP. But there are javascript events you can listen for and they actually work quite well; see [AddThis Client Api](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#events).

e.g.:

```
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', function( event ){
    // something was succesfully shared
    // save pertinent data for further use
    var service = event.data.service,
        link = event.data.url;

    // some ajax would go here to notify PHP, then redirect
});
```